# redirect to a page when clicked on text/div

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a panel having list group items, right now when I click on Survey name I get an popup with help of Bootstrap modal.
What I want to do is when I click on the blue headline or on list group item div I must get redirected to another page based on the **Status** of survey. Like when survey status is **Completed** on click it must get redirected to **Show result** if status is **Incomplete** must get redirected to **CompleteSurvey**.

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.PreviousPollSurveyDetails)
                    {
                        <div class="list-group">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">


                            <h4 class="mb-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pollcontent">@item.Name (@item.CategoryName)</h4>
                            <p class="mb-1">@item.Description</p>
                            <p class="mb-1 statuslist">Status :<span class="complTxt">Completed</span></p>
                            <p class="mb-2 datelist">
                                <b>From</b> @item.StartDate <b>To</b> @item.EndDate
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>                        }
                </div>
```

Here is how I'm creating Panel with list-group items.[When I click on Blue headline I want to get redirected to a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq0HW.png)

Comment: Then include the url in your `href` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke If there would be only one page I must have used href but here I'm redirecting based on **Status** condition. Also I updated the code. Sorry but I'm confused :/

Comment: Then create it based on that condition! - if (someCondition) { @Html.ActionLink(...) } else { @Html.ActionLink(...) }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Condition is **SurveyCompleted** if 2 then status is completed. This field is in my table and not in the same model which I'm using in this view so what I have planned is to call this filed to **Home Controller** in a method then through Ajax call checking this condition in view. This is what I have planned.

Comment: Then use a view model containing a property so that you can test the condition in the view.